# How to return the 2 ArrayList that was stored in this method, instead of just printing it in the void?

Tags: java

I just want my `checkerOddEven()` method to be an ArrayList type instead of void, and I want it to be able to return both Arraylist that was stored inside each variables, so that it will print out exactly like the current output with void method.

this is the output of the current code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCv1r.png)

```
int[] numbers;

public Main(){
    numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
}

public boolean oddEven (int number){

    if(number%2!=0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
public void checkerOddEven (int[] numbers){

    ArrayList<Integer> answerOdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> answerEven = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int number : numbers){
        if(oddEven(number)){
            answerOdd.add(number);
        }
        else answerEven.add(number);
    }

    System.out.println("The Odd numbers are :"+answerOdd);
    System.out.println("The Even numbers are :"+answerEven);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

    main.checkerOddEven(main.numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer>[] checkerOddEven (int[] numbers){
    ArrayList<Integer> list[]; // I create an Array of ArrayLists
    list = new ArrayList[2]; // I allocate memory for two ArrayLists inside that array. It's important to note that without this, trying to do list[0]=new ArrayList<>(); would have crashed, because there's no list[] yet.
    list[0] = new ArrayList<>();list[1] = new ArrayList<>(); //I create the ArrayList instances by calling their constructor

    for(int number : numbers){
        if(oddEven(number)){
            list[0].add(number);
        }
        else list[1].add(number);
    }

    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    ArrayList<Integer>[] listOfNumbers = (checkerOddEven(main.numbers));
    System.out.print("Odds: "); for(int i=0;i<listOfNumbers[0].size();i++) System.out.print(listOfNumbers[0].get(i)+" ");
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.print("Even: "); for(int i=0;i<listOfNumbers[1].size();i++) System.out.print(listOfNumbers[1].get(i)+" ");
}
```

Comment: Wait cmiiw, so we can store an arraylist inside the each index of an arraylist?

Comment: You can create arrays of objects. An ArrayList is just one object that has some particular methods and attributes, just as any other. So, as you can do int n[5] you can also do ArrayList n[5]. Be careful with allocating space for it tho, if I'd have skipped the "list = new ArrayList[2]" it would have crashed because there would be no space for each ArrayList. By doing that I allocated slots for two ArrayLists, but they were not instantiated yet, that's why I call the constructor below.

Comment: "You can store an arraylist inside each index of an arraylist" yes you do, but that's not what I did. What you said would be "ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list;"

Comment: But I don't think that makes sense. You know you want only two arraylists, so you use a structure that is easy to access not so easy to dynamically change (I chose an array). The benefit of an ArrayList is that you can add as many elements in it as you want, you wouldn't benefit from that if you know you only want two elements (in this case, two ArrayLists). You can read more about that here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-array-list

Comment: ok i tried the same exact thing in the method, but when i run, i display the memory allocation instead, not the arraylist that was returned,

Comment: aahh, umm but didnt you declare the list as ArrayList there? im confused o.o lol
what i caught is that, you declare an ArrayList named list, and then instantiate the index 0 and 1 as another ArrayList

Comment: I'll edit my answer so you can see the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer though, its on my end that doesnt quite get it yet

Comment: No worries, glad to help ^.^ please don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one if you found it useful

Comment: Feel free to comment here if something's yet unclear. Maybe you can just practice creating objects like these by yourself.

Comment: It is definitely helpful, and i totally got it now, thank you for the explanation!